# How to find out the groupid of com.learningstorm with Spring Tool?

Tags: eclipse, spring, apache-storm, archetypes

I'm reading a tutorial for Apache Storm and I want to create a Maven Project with groupid "com.learning storm". The problem is that this is missing. I have the following archetype catalogs added:

```
[http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml][1]
[http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.storm][2]
```

How can I find out the groupid of com.learning storm?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly. However, you can start a maven project simply as follows:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.learning.storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>learning-storm</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that when I search for com.learningstorm it is missing from the architype list. Is there some repository url which I can add to the catalogs ?

Comment: So what? Why do you need it to be contained in the archtype list?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a guess, if I understand correctly, you don't mean to just create a project, you mean to do so with Maven archetype of your choosing, namely the com.learning.storm one.

Well, here's some steps:

1. Hopefully they created it
2. And uploaded it to some repository you can access it from (Maven Central would be best, but if you can't find it, odds are against it).
3. you may run `mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=com.learning.storm` - it sets filter for archetype plugin to "storm", but on my machine it yields three results, none of which fit one you desire
4. you may run archetype plugin interactively and look for storm there (it also gives you filtering options, by group or artifact id, so knowing one, you are in luck). This is the same as option 3 though.
5. you may look for archetype catalog, it's an XML file. Each Maven repository has it (your local one included). Maven source repository also has one. If your com.learning.storm was submitted - you will see it in that XML.
6. you may go to Maven Central and look using their search - some archetypes are submitted also as projects or dependencies.
7. Go to site of those folks who own com.learning.storm -> storm.learning.com, that is, and search it for that information.